# android volley can't get response

Tags: android, response, android-volley

I am trying to get the response from instagram api using volley, but can't get the data. I did't receive any call back methods like onResponse or onErrorResponse. Nothing show up. I Could not see any error.

here is my code.

```
public String getUserId(String usrName) {
    url = TContants.urlBeforeUserId + usrName + TContants.urlAfterUser;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq;
    jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            TagsResponse gsonData = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), TagsResponse.class);
            userId = gsonData.data[0].id.toString();
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley:", "getUserId response error");
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
            TContants.tag_json_obj);
    return userId;
}
```

url is working fine, I tested it.

When code running JsonObjectRequest creating. but next step it skip the onResponse and onErrorResponse methods. plz help.

Comment: please learn how multithreading works ... http://ideone.com/PPHi95 <= as you can see in example at the end of `getUserId` , `userId` will be not set ...

Comment: Post your `AppController` code. IMO, you should replace `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
            TContants.tag_json_obj);` by `AppController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
            TContants.tag_json_obj);`

Answer (score 1):

The code inside onResponse is not skipped, that's how it's supposed to work, what you are looking at is a [Callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

A **very quick and general** explanation would be:
this code does not run serially, instead, onResponse in this case is your implementation of an interface provided by the request object, that will be called when the response arrives, this might take several milliseconds to seconds (depending on the server, since this callback is for a network operation).

Read about callback handling (both network, and the simple ones you create with interfaces - and if you haven't yet - read about interfaces), as it is a major part of programming.

ADDITION:

To see when the response does return, I would print all the parameters before sending them to make sure they are sent correctly, and also print the response itself (response.toString() at the beginning of onResponse) and wait a bit to see it after the request is sent.
(don't be alarmed if the print won't contain readable info, it depends on the implementation of the .toString() method, for now it's just an indication that you got a response at all).